# Adding soundtrack to a video using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

In short, I want to merge the audio from a video with a music source (mp3, aac...).

I have a video file with sound. I want to add a soundtrack to it so that the audio from the output file has speech and music.

I looked for several solutions but all I found was how to add another sound track as a choice between audio1 and audio2. Here is a sample I found :

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i music.mp3 -map 0 -map 1 \
   -vcodec copy -acodec copy merged.mp4
```

Also, I want the music to fit the video length (I think the `-shortest` option can achieve this, please confirm).

Many thanks !

Comment: Do you want to combine two input audio streams into one combined output stream? This is possible with ffmpeg. Please show the ffmpeg console output of your command. It will allow me to make an accurate example command.

Comment: I have a video with image and sound (input.mp4). I want to add a soundtrack (music.mp3) to this video. But I want the audio from input.mp4 merged with music.mp3 and retain the images from input.mp4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Two stereo inputs to one stereo output

You can use the [`amerge`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) audio filter to combine both audio streams into one stream, and then the [`pan`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan) audio filter to combine the resulting 4 channels into 2 channels (stereo). This is assuming that both of your inputs are stereo:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i music.mp3 -codec:v copy -codec:a aac -b:a 192k \
-strict experimental -filter_complex "amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3" \
-shortest output.mp4
```

- Since you only want to manipulate the audio `-codec:v copy` is used to [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the video.
- `-strict experimental` or `-strict -2` is needed to use the native FFmpeg AAC encoder. Also see the [FFmpeg and AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide) for other options and examples.
- The pan syntax `c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3` can be translated as, "for output channel `c0` (the left channel), combine the left channels of both inputs (input channels `c0` and `c2`), and for output channel `c1` (the right channel), combine the right channels of both inputs (input channels `c1` and `c3`)".
- `-shortest` will make the output duration the same as the duration of the shortest input.

#### Two mono inputs to one stereo output

This is easier but will simply copy the mono channel of each input to each channel of the output:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i music.mp3 -codec:v copy -codec:a aac -b:a 192k \
-strict experimental -ac 2 -shortest output.mp4
```

#### Also see

- [Manipulating audio channels with ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation)